# Files in Docker volumes not refeshing on Windows on file change

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I had Docker for Windows, switched to Docker toolbox and now back to Docker for Windows and I ran into the issues with Volumes.

Before volumes were working perfectly fine and my containers which running with nodemon/tsnode/CLI watching files were restarting properly on source code change, but now they don't at all, so it looks like file changes from host are not populated in the container.

This is docker-compose for one service:

```
api:
   build:
     context: ./api
     dockerfile: Dockerfile-dev
   volumes:
     - ./api:/srv
   working_dir: /srv
   links:
     - mongo
   depends_on:
     - mongo
   ports:
    - 3030:3030
   environment:
     MONGODB: mongodb://mongo:27017/api_test
   labels:
     - traefik.enable=true
     - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:api.mydomain.localhost
```

This id Dockerfile-dev

```
FROM node:10-alpine
ENV NODE_ENV development
WORKDIR /srv
EXPOSE 3030
CMD yarn dev // simply nodemon, working when ran from host
```

Can anyone help with that?
C drive is shared and verified with `docker run --rm -v c:/Users:/data alpine ls /data` showing list of files properly.

I will really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

We experienced the exact same problems in our team while developing nodejs/typescript applications with Docker on top of Windows and it has always been a big pain. To be honest, though, Windows does the right thing by not propagating the change event to the containers (Linux hosts also do not propagate the fsnotify events to containers unless the change is made from within the container). So bottom line: I do not think this issue will be avoidable unless you actually change the files within the container instead of changing them on the docker host. You can achieve this with a code sync tool like docker-sync, see this page for a list of available options: https://github.com/EugenMayer/docker-sync/wiki/Alternatives-to-docker-sync

**Because we struggled with such issues for a long time, a colleague and I started an open source project called DevSpace CLI: https://github.com/covexo/devspace**

The DevSpace CLI can establish a reliable and super fast 2-way code sync between your local folders and folders within your dev containers (works with any Kubernetes cluster, any volume and even with ephemeral / non-persistent folders) and it is designed to work perfectly with hot reloading tools such as nodemon. Setup minikube or a cluster with a one-click installer on some public cloud, run `devspace up` inside your project and you will be ready to program within your DevSpace without ever having to worry about local Docker issues and hot reloading problems. Let me know if it works for you or if there is anything you are missing.

Answer (score 0):

I've been stuck into this recently (Feb 2020, Docker Desktop 2.2) and nothing from the base solutions really helped.

However when I tried [WSL 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-install) and ran my `docker-compose` from inside Ubuntu shell, it became to pick up the changes in the files instantly. So if someone is observing this - try to up Docker from WSL 2.